# Validation on dynamically generated fields

Tags: angularjs

I am working on the dynamically generated fields and validation on it in AngularJs but for some reason it's not working.

I am new with angular, can some one please help me to make it work?

Here is a link to the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krunalcp/otvxjfux/1/)

HTML part is below.

Max length: 10
             Allowed: Only Numbers
          
          
            Max length: 4
             Allowed: Only Numbers
          
        
      
      
        
           Add another contact

JavaScript part

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

   angular.module('app').controller(
   'specialConditionsController', [
      '$scope', '$log', '$window', '$http', 'SweetAlert',
  function (
    $scope, $log, $window, $http, SweetAlert
) {
  var counterAuthorisedPerson = 0;
  var maxContactCountAllowed = 3;

  $scope.tetboxContactInformationAuthorisedPersonFullName = [
    {
        authorisedPersonFullName: 'AuthorizedPersonproviderFullName_' + counterAuthorisedPerson,
        providerFullName: '',
        authorisedPersonPhone: 'AuthorizedPersonContactPhone_' + counterAuthorisedPerson,
        providerPhoneNumber: '',
        authorisedPersonPhoneExt: 'AuthorizedPersonContactPhoneExt_' + counterAuthorisedPerson,
        providerPhoneExtension: ''
    }
  ];

  $scope.addAnotherContactforAuthorisedPerson = function () {
    if (counterAuthorisedPerson == maxContactCountAllowed) {
      alert("Upto Four contacts are allowed");
      return;
    } else {
      counterAuthorisedPerson++;
      $scope.tetboxContactInformationAuthorisedPersonFullName.push({
        authorisedPersonFullName: 'AuthorizedPersonproviderFullName_' + counterAuthorisedPerson,
        providerFullName: '',
        authorisedPersonPhone: 'AuthorizedPersonContactPhone_' + counterAuthorisedPerson,
        providerPhoneNumber: '',
        authorisedPersonPhoneExt: 'AuthorizedPersonContactPhoneExt_' + counterAuthorisedPerson,
        providerPhoneExtension: ''
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
   }
 ])
})(angular);
```

Comment: what exactly the issue, i check the fiddle and foun this error on console, `Uncaught Error: No module: app` also i make a plknr with your code and is incomplete cause you refered to some variables who doesnt exist.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco Thanks for your message. The variable I used is from some other form(asp file). I am using JsFiddle to show it to some one.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco it would be great if you would make a plnkr. :)

Comment: i cant make a usable plknr because your example is incomplete and i dont know what exactly doesnt work with your code casue your fiddle you provide have issues with variables doesnt work. i replicate in this link but still unknow some variables.  https://embed.plnkr.co/1qUike5s3wkNtM8jbwda/